# how to have a class variable reference an external object

Tags: c++

I have the following piece of code

https://godbolt.org/z/n6doeTfGa

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class mainClass
{
    public:
    mainClass(std::vector<int>& outvect) : m_vec(outvect)
    {}
    auto iterate() -> void
    {
        for (auto& elem : m_vec)
            std::cout << elem << std::endl;
    }
    private:
    std::vector<int> m_vec;
};


int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{1,2,3};
    auto classObj = mainClass(v);
    v.push_back(4);
    classObj.iterate();
}
```

Now the program just prints 1,2,3. But I would like for it also print all the change that happen to `v`.

I was able to come up with this solution.

https://godbolt.org/z/ca4xrhxeE

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class mainClass
{
    public:
    mainClass(std::vector<int>& outvect) : m_vec(&outvect)
    {}
    auto iterate() -> void
    {
        for (auto& elem : *m_vec)
            std::cout << elem << std::endl;
    }
    private:
    std::vector<int>* m_vec;
};


int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{1,2,3};
    auto classObj = mainClass(v);
    v.push_back(4);
    classObj.iterate();
}
```

But is there a **cleaner** way to do this without using pointers?

Comment: References or shared_ptr

Comment: @MikeVine but won't references have to be declared at the time of definition of `m_vec`

Comment: the "cleaner" way would be to not use a class but a free function that gets a reference to the vector passed on each call

Comment: @Morpheous The question "won't references have to be declared at the time of definition of `m_vec`" doesn't make sense.   Definitions ARE declarations, not the reverse.    And, if a reference is a member of a class, the class constructors can initialise it in their initialiser list.

Comment: @Peter I assume in this case I have to delete the default constructor (if it is defined) ?

Comment: @Morpheus - Not necessarily.   But bear in mind there are implications of a class having reference members - and the definition of constructors and assignment operators often needs to address those implications.

Comment: I would design API of `mainClass` in different way. For example instead passing vector to constructor I would pass it as argument of `mainClass::iterate`. Anyway I think this is [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem), you should provide more context explaining why you think you need this approach so someone could propose better alternative solution.

Answer (score 2):

Just use references:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class mainClass
{
    public:
    mainClass(std::vector<int>& outvect) : m_vec(outvect)
    {}
    auto iterate() -> void
    {
        for (auto& elem : m_vec)
            std::cout << elem << std::endl;
    }
    private:
    std::vector<int>& m_vec;
};


int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{1,2,3};
    auto classObj = mainClass(v);
    v.push_back(4);
    classObj.iterate();
}
```

Comment: you should mention the implications of having a reference member

Comment: in this case everything is ok but what about if the original `vector` goes outside scope and `mainClass` doesn't... a crash for sure or undefined behaviour

Answer (score 1):

As you are asking for a "clean" way, this is what I would prefer:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

auto iterate(auto m_vec) {
    for (auto& elem : m_vec)
        std::cout << elem << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v{1,2,3};
    v.push_back(4);
    iterate(v);
}
```

Reference members have some unpleasant implications (eg no copies) that are usually unwanted for anything but short-lived helper/wrapper objects. Using a pointer member opens another can of worms: ownership. Who owns the vector? Who makes sure that the vector is still alive when `iterate` is using it? Smart pointers can help with that. Though as there is no state in your class (other than the reference to the vector which is supposed to be managed outside of the class) I see no reason to write a class.

You can bind a reference to the vector to the free function via a lambda expression:

```
int main() {        
    std::vector<int> v{1,2,3};
    auto iterator = [&](){ iterate(v); };
    v.push_back(4);
    iterator();
}
```

With a lambda it is a little more obvious that it captures by reference and can only be used as long as the vector is alive. By using the lambda you also avoid all headaces mentioned above that come with raw pointer or reference member of self written class.

Comment: I feel like a jerk now as the example I provided was me  just trying to provide a minimal working example.  There is an actual class that is bigger but has to have a m_vec as a member.

Comment: @Morpheus I was expecting that somehow ;). I tried to answer the question as it stands. And note that you are asking for a clean way to do "this", where "this" can only refer to the code you posted. (btw please do not change the question to ask for a class with more additional members, because that would turn the question into a compeltely different question)

Comment: Thanks! Nevertheless you answer was very insightful.